Tokenizer splits the special word
I am trying to train  bytepiecetokenizer on my data. I have added some special words which I do not want to tokenized further. But when I use RobertaTokenizer to tokenize a sentence which contains the special word, the special word is tokenized.
My code for training tokenizer:
`from tokenizers import BertWordPieceTokenizer, ByteLevelBPETokenizer
files = 'file.txt'
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer(
lowercase=True,
)
And then train
tokenizer.train(
files,
vocab_size=100000,
min_frequency=5,
show_progress=True,
special_tokens=["", "", "", "", "", "auto_part", "bokchoy"],
)
`
Save the files
tokenizer.save_model('bpe_piece') 
Test the tokenizer:
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('bpe_piece') print(tokenizer.tokenize('an bokchoy auto_part))
Output should be ['an', 'bokchoy', 'auto_part']
But instead the output is ['an', 'Ġbok', 'choy', 'Ġauto', '_', 'part']
